Interactive grid data can't be changed
I have a page in master - detail relation.
The master part is a form on master table including an item with type LOV and the detail part in type of Interactive grid.
When I choose the QT_CODE in the master(lov item) and submit the page all items related to this QT_CODE can be inserted into the detail table (the Interactive grid).
I want to edit on column QTY and the column TOTAL_COST edited automatically as QTY * UNIT_PRICE.
I tried to do that with creating a trigger before insert on
stk_trans_details as
:new.total_cost = :new.qty * :new.unit_price
but the QTY and the TOTAL_COST can't be updated.
I disabled the trigger and created a dynamic action on QTY,UNIT_PRICE: When it is changed, set value QTY * UNIT_PRICE.
Affected element is TOTAL_COST but the values can't be changed too.
I canceled the dynamic action and created process to update the table with the new values. All of these ways I can't change the data.
Could somebody help me?
